# How to chain multiple paging request with node-apac?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise, amazon-product-api

I'm new to Javascript and Nodejs and I am trying to setup a server which can request multiple ItemPages from amazon-product-api via the [node-apac](https://github.com/dmcquay/node-apac) node package. So far my http server is up and running with some routes defined. I can also request a single ItemPage. But I have trouble chaining the requests.

example for theQuery:

```
var query = {
    Title: theTitle,
    SearchIndex: 'Books',
    BrowseNodeId: '698198',
    Power: 'binding:not (Kindle or Kalender)',
    Sort: '-publication_date',
    ResponseGroup: 'ItemAttributes,Images',
    ItemPage: 1
};
```

the code:

```
AmazonWrapper.prototype.getAllPagesForQuery = function(theMethod, theQuery, theResultCallback) {    
    client.execute(theMethod, theQuery).then(function(theResult) {
        var pageCount = theResult.result.ItemSearchResponse.Items.TotalPages;
        var requests = [];
        for(var i = 2; i < pageCount; i++) {
            theQuery.ItemPage = i;
            requests.push(client.execute(theMethod, theQuery));     
        }
        Promise.all(requests).then(function(theResults) {       
            var data = theResults[0];
            for(var i = 1; i < theResults.length; i++) {
                var items = theResults[i].result.ItemSearchResponse.Items.Item;
                data.result.ItemSearchResponse.Items.Item.concat(items);
            }
            theResultCallback(data);
        });
    });
};
```

As you see I want to read from the first request how many Itempages are available for my ItemSearch und create a new request for each Itempage. Unfortunately Promise.all(...).then() is never called.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: added sample for theQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`theQuery` looks like an object.  As such, it is passed by pointer to when you do `theQuery.ItemPage = i` and then you pass `theQuery`, you're passing the same object to every single request and just overwriting the `ItemPage` property on that one object.  This is unlikely to work properly.

I don't know exactly what `theQuery` is, but you probably need to make copy of it.

Also, you may as well return a promise from `.getAllPagesForQuery()` rather than use a callback since you're already using promises.  Error handling and chaining is a whole lot easier with promises all the way through.

You don't quite disclose enough code, but here's the general idea for how to fix:

```
AmazonWrapper.prototype.getAllPagesForQuery = function(theMethod, theQuery) {    
    return client.execute(theMethod, theQuery).then(function(theResult) {
        var pageCount = theResult.result.ItemSearchResponse.Items.TotalPages;
        var requests = [];
        for(var i = 2; i < pageCount; i++) {
            // make unique copy of theQuery object
            var newQuery = Object.assign({}, theQuery);
            newQuery.ItemPage = i;
            requests.push(client.execute(theMethod, newQuery));     
        }
        return Promise.all(requests).then(function(theResults) {       
            var data = theResults[0];
            for(var i = 1; i < theResults.length; i++) {
                var items = theResults[i].result.ItemSearchResponse.Items.Item;
                 data.result.ItemSearchResponse.Items.Item = data.result.ItemSearchResponse.Items.Item.concat(items);
            }
            return data;
        });
    });
};

// Usage example:
obj.getAllPagesForQuery(...).then(function(data) {
    // process returned data here
});
```

Comment: cool its now performing the requests and entering all().then() but theResults is an array of functions instead of an array of response data. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @JacobZ - I don't fully follow what data.result.ItemSearchResponse.Items.Item` is.  But, `.concat()` returns a new array (it doesn't modify the one you call `.concat()` on so you at least need to assign the result of that to something.  I updated that part of my question, but you don't really explain what your trying to do inside the `for(var i = 1; i < theResults.length; i++) {...}` loop so I'm not sure what else might be wrong there.

Comment: theResult is an Object which represents the response from the amazon-product-api call. within this object is an array of product items with path `theResult.result.ItemSearchResponse.Items.Item`.

I expect that `theResults` in `all().then() ` is an array of objects representing the amazon response. instead it is an array of functions. That dosen't let me merge the Item arrays since  `theResults` is not the datastructure I expect. Does this make any sense?

Comment: @JacobZ - `theResults` will be an array of whatever the `client.execute()` promise fulfills with.